# CPU time measurement

Tags: c++, c, linux, timing

I have following code snippet and i am trying to evaluate the time take by CPU

However I am getting some weird results

```
struct timeval begin, end;
double cpu_time=0.0;
gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);
long cpu_sum = 0;


for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 cpu_sum += array[i] * array[i];
}    
 gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
 cpu_time = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec * 1000;
 cpu_time += (end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec) / 1000;

 printf("calculated sum: %d using CPU in %lf ms \n", cpu_sum, cpu_time);
```

Sample result = 1296217442.000000 ms

I dont think this is correct time value in ms. 
Can anyone help whats wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want **CPU** time, you probably want to use [`clock_gettime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) instead with the `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` parameter.

That's the probably most convenient (and accurate) way to get both real time and cpu time using the same function, only changing one parameter.

Comment: although be aware that it's not portable - `getrusage()` is the POSIX defined function.

Comment: @Alnitak, why do you think this is not portable? It is (optional) part of POSIX as well. And if you really want to be portable, `clock` from the C library might be a better choice. Concerning user time this should give you the same information as `getrusage`.

Comment: @JensGustedt it doesn't exist on MacOS X, nor FreeBSD.

Comment: @user958263 ah, nice - accept the answer that didn't even call out the real math problem in your question...

Comment: @Alnitak, the OP tagged with linux. And as I said, then `clock` is a better choice, returns just an integer, simple to use.

Comment: @Alnitak, but I agree with you that accepting this answer here and not yours that dig out the real problem with his/her code, is a bit extreme.

Answer (score 13):

You need to fix your operator precedence:

```
cpu_time = (end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) * 1000;
cpu_time += (end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec) / 1000;
```

In the original you're multiplying `begin.tv_sec` by 1000, and *then* subtracting that from `end.tv_sec`;

Also, not that `gettimeofday()` measures "wall clock time", not strictly CPU time, where the latter is the better measure of how much "CPU effort" the process took.  If another process uses the CPU at the same time as yours then the results will not be accurate.

For "proper" CPU time you should use the (POSIX standard) `getrusage()` system call.

Answer (score 1):

Pentium class cpu has an instruction to read the current time-stamp counter variable ,which is a 64-bit variable, into registers (edx:eax).If you want get real CPU time,you can use this instruction.You can get CPU tick.
Details... this link,please.
[rdtsc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~kazutomo/rdtsc.html)

Answer (score 0):

A small addition to Alnitak's answer:

You define `cpu_time` as `double`, I assume it's in order to handle possible overflows (run time greater than ~2M seconds).
But in the line:

```
cpu_time = (end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) * 1000;
```

The right-hand side is evaluated as an `unsigned integer`, and will overflow after about 4M seconds. Assigning it to a `double` afterwards won't help.
So if you really care about long run times, do this:

```
cpu_time = (double)(end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) * 1000;
```

Comment: @Alnitak, Indeed it would, but I think the cast is more clear.